# deploy eclipse utility project as jar file in ear lib folder

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ear, jboss-eap-6

Below is my project deployment structure

    `myapp.ear
    ...META-INF
    ......application.xml
    ...lib
    ......myUtility.jar
    ...myejb.jar
    ...mywar.war`

myUtility.jar is an eclipse project which I want to deploy in ear lib folder. But When I add the project in ear deployment assembly, it gets deployed in ear root as module instead of lib. 
I am deploying my app on jboss EAP run time environment and maven is not used in my project.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of project is myUtility.jar?  What's contained in it's META-INF or WEB-INF folder, e.g. the files?

Comment: @JGlass its has only META-INF folder with MANIFEST.MF. Manifest file contain the basic information which is auto generated. the jar contains the util classes which is shared library for ejb and web module.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be being identified as a WAR or EJB if there were web.xml or ejb-jar.xml files.  Which part of the app depends on it, the EJB or the WAR or both?

Comment: Both EJB and War depends on the utility jar

Comment: Then try and add "myUtility.jar" to the deployment assembly of both the war and and ejb projects, nothing else should be referencing it.  This should cause the Eclipse to then place myUtility.jar in the ear's lib folder.  If it works let me know and I'll add it as an answer ;-) Also double check the EAR doesnt just happen to contain a copy or old copy of myUtility.jar by verifying in the file system,

Comment: @JGlass Sorry.. was working on something else so couldn't try this earlier. So I removed utility jar from ear modules but the compilation for utility project failed coz it is dependent on library jars from EarContent\lib. I added required libs to utility project manually. And utility project is already added for deployment assembly of war and ear. Now after clean and publish, utlityJar didn't get deployed on jboss run-time env.

Comment: No worries, make sure myUtility.jar is added to the deployment assembly for the war or ejb jar or both if they both depend on it, this then should cause eclipse to package it up in the EAR lib folder on deployment

Comment: I have tried that, but myUtility.jar is not deployed in ear lib and application deployment fails with classNotFoundException

Comment: It sounds like your projects may be corrupted as what I said should work and thats how I do things...  Only thing I can think of is to create a new set of bare bone projects, e.g. create a new war and ejb project(s), then create ear and add both them to deployment assembly of ear, then create your utility project, add it to the build path of the war and ejb and then set it in the deployment assembly of both.  If that doesnt work, try again, create war and ejb projects, create utility project and add it to build path and deployment assembly of both, then create the ear and add war and ejb to it

Comment: **First** You can also try with what you currently have removing the utility from the deployment assembly of the war and ejb but leave it on build path. Then go to ears deployment assembly and add the utility project to it. Push comes to shove I could get the barebones project setup and if I can get it to work, I could put them up on GitHub and you could pull them down, import them, then add your code to them